# TSQL Update with inline, grouping and between

Tags: t-sql

I want to update a date from the earliest start date which occurs between the current date and the original date. The query I have is:

```
update TableA
set [Stop_Date] =DATA.Min_Start
FROM TableA
JOiN
    (select min(TableB.START_DTTM ) as Min_Start
            from TableB
            where 
                TableB.CancelReason ='Treatment'            AND
                TableA.Start_Date>=TableB.START_DTTM        AND
                TableB.START_DTTM  '< GETDATE()
        ) DATA
            ON          TableA.Ref_No=TableB.REFRL_REFNO
            where
                [Stop_Date] is null
```

But `TableA.Start_Date` seems to cause a problem.  Can anyone help with the correct SQL?

Here is some test data:

```
DECLARE @TableA TABLE  (Ref_No Int, Stop_Date DateTime,Start_Dat DateTime)
DECLARE @TableB TABLE (REFRL_REFNO int, CancelReason varchar(50), START_DTTM DateTime,
    Stop_DTTM DateTime,Comments varchar(50))
insert @TableA
select 1,               '10 jan 2000',              '5 jan 2000'
insert @TableA
select 4,               NULL,                       '9 jan 2000'
insert @TableB
select 1,'Treatment','8 Jan 2000','9 Jan 2000','Shouldn''t be used'
insert @TableB
select 4,'Treatment','1 Jan 2000','2 Jan 2000','Shouldn''t be used'
insert @TableB
select 4,'Treatment','21 Jan 2000','22 Jan 2000','Shouldn''t be used'
insert @TableB
select 4,'Treatment','11 Jan 2000','12 Jan 2000','Should be used'
insert @TableB
select 4,'Other','10 Jan 2000','11 Jan 2000','Shouldn''t be used'
```

Comment: `... AND TableB.START_DTTM)` - this doesn't look like a complete expression.

Comment: Sorry, the '<' sign didn't come through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition `TableA.Start_Date>=TableB.START_DTTM AND TableB.START_DTTM '< GETDATE()` is wrong. This restricts TableB values to those before the startdate and less than current date not those between the two.

The below appears to work.

```
UPDATE    TableA
SET  Stop_Date = 
   (
   SELECT MIN(TableB.START_DTTM)  
   FROM TableB 
   WHERE 
     TableA.Ref_No = TableB.REFRL_REFNO
   AND (TableB.CancelReason = 'Treatment') 
   AND (TableB.START_DTTM BETWEEN TableA.[Start_Date] AND GETDATE())
   )
WHERE (TableA.Stop_Date IS NULL)
```